# TFS 2018 Update 2 IIS Website Deployment Deprecated or missing

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

After updating TFS to update 2, in the CI build tasks "IIS Web App Deployment" is marked as Deprecated. Whats the replacement for this task?

[image]Also in the CD in the after adding "IIS Website Deployment Template" the IIS Web App Manage and IIS Web App Deploy tasks are marked with 
*This task is no longer installed. Re-install the task or remove it from your definition.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just love it when Microsoft changes things out of the blue without clear, available documentation!

It looks like they deprecated these to make way for Marketplace apps. You should add the first one in the list, "**IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM**".

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp

I've no idea why this isn't "installed" in TFS by default, since it is Microsoft's own solution. Instead, you get the pleasant experience of:

- Realizing midway through your Release configuration that the one you were used to using is now suddenly deprecated
- Researching the replacement on SO
- Clicking "Get Now" on the new IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM item.
- Adding it to your TFS account, presuming you have access to do so without having to kick the request up the chain to your TFS instance owner or manager.
- Saving your release pipeline in progress, because TFS doesn't "see" that you have the new IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM item until the whole pipeline task creator reloads.
- Finding and re-opening the pipeline in progress you just saved, only to re-open it and continue editing to complete your initial task.

Cheers!

Comment: I am not using WinRM to deploy web-apps. I have configured only "IIS web app deploy" task which is now direct missing while creating a new release. also in Marketplace only "IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM" is showing. Can't I have "IIS web app deploy" back ?

Comment: Strange how my existing tasks still work.  This feels like they are trying to market a product by removing another.